# ruby, trying to return a subset of multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

**I am trying to return a subset of a multi-dimensional array, trying to keep the exact structure of dimensions, but.. something strange is happening... take a look please:**

```
space = [  [ [1],[2],[3] ],  [ [4],[5],[6] ],  [ [70],[8],[9] ]  ]

space_subset = space[(1..2)].collect { |y| y[1] }

=> [[5], [8]]
```

Let's break it down:

```
space[(1..2)]

=> [  [ [4], [5], [6] ], [ [70], [8], [9] ]  ]
```

so now I can be sure what I am calling .collect on

in fact:

```
[  [ [4], [5], [6] ], [ [70], [8], [9] ]  ].collect { |y| y[1] }

=> [[5], [8]]
```

Then... (for the real question)...

If now space_subset is [[5], [8]]

and I try to modify it like this:

```
space_subset[1].delete (8)
```

and as expected I get: `=> [[5], []]`

**why does this at the same time modifies the original "space" array from which I *extracted* the subset array ?**

If now I do:

```
space

=> [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[70], [], [9]]]
```

"8" is missing, the same value I deleted from the space_subset

I am looking at ruby Array api docs and from what I am reading my code should work without surprises... but.. still.....

Can you help me figure what I'm doing wrong, or misunderstanding here ?

Thanks to everyone who takes the time to answer

Comment: btw, 70 is in place of 7 for no particual reason, I apologize if it creates confusion.

Comment: `space_subset` contains the reference to both `[5]` and `[8]` arrays, not their values. So if you alter it in `space_subset`, it will affect `space` as well.

Comment: wait, isn't space_subset a _new object_ which is _equal_ to what I am assigning it to ? So why it should contain a reference and not it's own values ? Bringing it to the simplest: a = 10; b = a; b = 20; a => 10. "a" is still 10, because b is another object with its own value, not a reference to "a". So I don't see why you say it should work differently in my question example ?

Comment: Array does not work the same way than Fixnum.

Comment: Can you elaborate or provide documentation for your statements ?

Comment: Just see it by yourself. `a = []; b = a; a.object_id == b.object_id`

Comment: Your example omits the fact that after making b = a, I am assinging b a new value! If after what you say, I do "b = [[]]" then b owns a different value and not anymore a reference to a. In fact, afterward, a.object_id is different from b.object_id and if I change "b", "a" is not changed.

Comment: `Space` and `Space_subset` are not the same, but your `y[1]` is where you are copying a reference, and not cloning its value. See `space[2][1].object_id == space_subset[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a difference between **reference** and **value**. In your code, you create a reference to the inner arrays, but you are referencing the same values in both places. You can confirm this by calling `Object#object_id` on both arrays (as if changing the value via one reference and seeing be modified from the other reference isn't confirmation enough!).

```
space = [  [ [1],[2],[3] ],  [ [4],[5],[6] ],  [ [70],[8],[9] ]  ]
=> [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[70], [8], [9]]] 
space[2][1].object_id
=> 70329700053380 
space_subset = space[(1..2)].collect { |y| y[1] }
=> [[5], [8]] 
space_subset[1].object_id
=> 70329700053380
```

Unfortunately, `Array#dup` and `Array#clone` only make "shallow" copies of objects, so you have to use a bit of a workaround to get a copy of `space` to work with. One easy trick to get a deep copy is:

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(space))
```

You can also write a recursive function to take `space` and manually copy it into a new array.

And just to prove it:

```
space = [  [ [1],[2],[3] ],  [ [4],[5],[6] ],  [ [70],[8],[9] ]  ]
=> [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[70], [8], [9]]]
space[2][1].object_id
=> 70329700053380
space_subset = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(space))
=> [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[70], [8], [9]]]
space_subset = space_subset[(1..2)].collect { |y| y[1] }
=> [[5], [8]]
space_subset[1].object_id
=> 70329695297500
space_subset[1].delete(8)
=> 8
space
=> [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[70], [8], [9]]]
space_subset
=> [[5], []]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok thanks from the detailed answer but... from Array api doc, .collect method: Invokes block once for each element of self. Creates _a new array_ containing the values returned by the block. So shouldn't space_subset yield a totally new _copy_ of space ?

Comment: `collect` does create a new array, but the items contained **within** that array (the values returned by the block with `y[1]`) are references to the original `[5]` and `[8]` arrays. Another way to attack your problem is to call `dup` inside your collect block (since you are dealing with the lowest level of nesting, the shallow copy is no longer an issue): `space_subset = space[(1..2)].collect { |y| y[1].dup }` that will return a new array with a copy of the `[5]` and `[8]` values that will be independent of `space`. Clear as mud?

Comment: Yea, after reading this and many other answers to pass by value/reference questions now the mud it's starting to get cleaner :) By the way I haven't thanked you enough for your comprehensive answer! I really appreciated it! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Remember that in Ruby that not only is everything an object but that a variable is always a *reference* to an object. You're expecting a copy to be made here when what you're getting instead is a reference to the original single-element array.

This is why there are `clone` or `dup` methods on many objects. If you intend to modify something before using it, but do not want to mangle the original, make a copy and work with that.

An easy way to do this is to avoid using in-place modifiers like `delete` and instead use one like `reject`:

```
space_subset[1] = space_subset[1].reject { |v| v == 8 }
```

This will remove a single element and return a *copy* of the original array minus that element. This isn't necessarily the best way to go about doing it, though. A better approach
might be to simply "subtract" the elements you don't want as that also returns a copy:

```
space_subset[1] -= [ 8 ]
```

In general you must be wary of using in-place modifiers on data you don't "own". To be safe, you should use operations that produce a modified copy.